# What do the Sass lightness, lighten, and darken functions actually do?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am confused about the difference between the [lightness](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#lightness-instance_method), [lighten](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#lighten-instance_method), and [darken](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#darken-instance_method) functions. How do they change color value? Is it change color opacity/alpha value? What the difference between them?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out?

Comment: i tried but still confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Darken and Lighten, the color which you use gets parsed into HSL. HSL is a different color system which gets the Color from three different values "Hue", "Saturation" and "Lightness". In the Lighten or darken Function, the Lightness of the HSL Color gets manipulated.

The lightness function returns the "lightness" value of the calculated HSL Color.

You can read a bit about SASS Color functions [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/controlling-color-with-sass-color-functions)

Comment: Lighten() changes the color with the specified "Lightness" value. The Lightness()  function just returns the "Lightness" value of the color and changes nothing.